# AsyncTask while screen locked or overlapped by other app

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

There is a fragment page with "Submit" action.
Submit button will launch AsyncTask.execute which makes some network job in doInBackground, then will show success Toast message and remove itself in onPostExecute.

How to avoid "*IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState*” in situation when screen already switched off in moment when onPostExecute happened ?

Is it possible to wait for operations like popBackStack() or onBackPressed() when they can't be done in locked activity state ?

PS
Current question not connected with screen rotation or other configuration changes events.

Code Example (AsyncTask from fragment):

```
private final class SubmitTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        //...
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String err) {
            if (err != null) {
                Toast.makeText(parentActivity, "Error occured: " + err, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(parentActivity, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                parentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();// <<---- Exception crashed here
            }
        }
```

Comment: In your Toast command, instead of you using your current context, use getApplicationContext() and see if this prevents the exception

Comment: No it doesn't - the problem is probably not with the toast, but rather with some UI interactions after onSaveInstanceState() is called, so the activity is in illegal state to perform such action.

Comment: IllegalStateException is caused by fragmentManager.popBackStack(), which used to close current fragment and return to previous.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is just

```
try{....}

catch(IllegalStateException e){

}
```

Comment: Such code is possible, as well as interrupt current AsyncTask with cancel method from onPause, but I do not think it's correct behavior, because AsyncTask does his background job correctly and all it remain to do is close current fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Use [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) instead of `AsyncTask` and perform your work in `onHandleIntent()`. It is background and independant of `Fragment's` lifecycle, it also work in a worker (background) thread.

A downside of this aproach comes form the independance from `Fragment` or `Activity` - you don't have a `Context` there and you can't show your `Toast`. But this is fair price for agility that you need and you still can send a `Notification` or do anything related with `Intent` - start a new `Activity` or send a broadcast.